# How can I do validate that a checkbox is selected in KARATE UI testing?

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox, frameworks, karate

- def scr = scriptAll('assert(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div/p-checkbox/div/div[2]/span")).isSelected())')
- match scr == true

I tried this way but I think logic is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what all that `assert / await` stuff is for. Karate is NOT Selenium. Please read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locators

I think JS should work for you:

```
* def checked = script('someLocator', '_.checked')
* print 'checked:', checked
```